# After connecting SSL certificate to the frontend, requests are not sent to the backend

Tags: node.js, frontend, ssl-certificate, backend

Everything worked fine. But after after adding the SSL certificate to the frontend, requests are not sent to the backend. Backend has SSL certificate as well. Any ideas how I can fix it? Also added a forced use https.

In browser console I get: xhr.js:177 POST 188.221.82.95:3001/submitVideo/storageSize net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSE

Comment: How did you "connect SSL certificate to frontend"? Check browser console for debugging.

Comment: Have you tried listening on port 443?

Comment: I get the following error: xhr.js:177 POST https://188.221.82.95:3001/submitVideo/storageSize net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: just tried 443 port. Doesn't work :\